# Mobius Map from disk to itself that has no fixed points

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, dynamical-systems, mobius-transformation

If I have a Mobius map $f: \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ that has no fixed points in the disk. Is it true that every orbit of $f$ escapes any compact set $K \subset \mathbb{D}$?

If so, I'm a little stuck on seeing how.

Also, a small side question, if $f$ does have a fixed point, must $f$ be a rotation? If $0$ is the fixed point, then I understand that it is a rotation, but I am not sure for an arbitrary fixed point.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: maps on unit disc induce other maps on upper half plane, and for example a translation of the half plane has every orbit escaping each compact set. [Don't know if this is what you're after]

Comment: And so is it true that a mobius map on the disk that has no fixed points corresponds to a translation on the upper half plane?

Comment: I don't know whether there are other fixed point free maps on upper half plane model without fixed points, but what happens when one sets $f(z)=z$ assuming $f$ is fractional linear map on upper half-plane model? That is, there is a formula for these appropriate for upper half plane model one can look up, with the appropriate restrictions. [been a while for me but it could be googled...]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_fractional_transformation

Comment: Ah I think I see. How does this sound: we can extend $f:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ to $\bar{f} :\bar{\mathbb{D}} \rightarrow \bar{\mathbb{D}}$ and by Brouwers fixed point theorem, there must exist a fixed point on $\partial \mathbb{D}$. On translating this problem to $\mathbb{H}$, our problem becomes of the form $z \rightarrow z+ \alpha$ for some $\alpha\neq 0$. Like you said, it is clear that orbits always escape a compact set in this form, and so the result is true for $f$.

Comment: It does not have to be a translation, could be a dilation. Up to conjugation, there is nothing else.

Comment: As in it could be of the form $z \rightarrow \alpha z$? So that means the orbit of any non-zero point escapes any compact set. This may sound silly, but where does $0\in \mathbb{H}$ correspond to in the disk when we translate the problem? @MoisheKohan

Comment: Yes. It is a fixed point on the boundary of the unit disk (and so is the point corresponding to $\infty$).